# Executing sql query using placeholders in racket

Tags: sql, scheme, racket

```
(query-exec 
   connect_
   "insert [Registration].[dbo].[Code] values (= ? , = ?)" 
   (first i) 
   (second i))
```

I'm trying to execute a sql query in racket using placeholders, I've tried using documentation to execute this query, but upon using the placeholders nothing seems to work, I'm using an obdc engine and sql server, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

There are several things that could be going on here.

Having taken a quick look at the SQL server docs, though, I *strongly* suspect that the problem has nothing do to with placeholders, but in your use of square brackets. [This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transact-sql-syntax-conventions-transact-sql) suggests that the brackets in the examples are "optional syntax items. Do not type the brackets."

More generally, I would expect to debug this by trying a query that *doesn't* have parameters, to see whether that's actually causing the problem.

As always, apologies if I'm mistaken, or telling you things you already know.

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the `=` signs:

```
(query-exec connect_
            "insert [Registration].[dbo].[Code] values (?, ?)" 
            (first i) 
            (second i))
```

That assumes there are two columns in the table (or if there are more then the others have default values). I generally prefer to give the field names explicitly, like

```
INSERT INTO tablename (field1, field2) values (?, ?)
```

Comment: Throws an invalid precision error, the syntax of the code isn't wrong, its weird because this wouldn't normally be an issue for me in other languages

Comment: @johncenator it might be a bug in the Racket ODBC code, then. Are the fields numeric or decimal? Also, does the error message show you a SQLSTATE field?

Comment: The values im trying to insert are strings from an object, not numeric or decimal values, i was going to try and use native sql client instead, it might not be possible through obdc server